# Incrementing the value attribute of Select option using Python Selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-select

I want to increment the value of "i" so that it can loop it to the next value in the drop down after a task is executed. I tried with for loop as well. In both the cases the output states as "argument of type 'int' is not iterable". Any reference of executing it will be appreciated.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "court_code"))
i = 1
while (i<=7):
    select.select_by_value(i)
    i += 1
```

This is the html code for reference:

```
<option value="0">Option 1</option>
<option value="1">Option 2</option>
.
<option value="7">Option 6</option>
<option value="8">Option 7</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *`while()`* loop:

```
while (i<=7):
```

***`i`*** is of type ***integer***, where as the argument ***value*** in [`select_by_value(value)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_value) accepts a *`string`*.

---

### Solution

You need to convert the type of the variable **i** from ***integer*** to ***string*** while passing as an argument to `select_by_value()` as follows:

```
while (i<=7):
    select.select_by_value(str(i))
    i += 1
```